# How to order posts by parents?

Tags: order, pre-get-posts

I wanted to order my post type archive by its parents (like page list in wp-admin).

This is what i have tried, but no luck so far.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'budget_archive_data' );

function budget_archive_data($query){
    $main_budget = array(3,4);

    if ( (is_post_type_archive('account') || is_post_type_archive('budget')) && $query->is_main_query() ) {     

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'parent' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $main_budget );

    }
}
```

The result was:

- Post 2 whose post_parent is 0
- Post 3 whose post_parent is 0
- Post 6 whose parent is 0
- Post 4  whose parent is 2
- Post 5 whose parent is 3

Anyone can help? Thanks before.

Comment: It should work - at least it looks like it should. What results do you get? Does your action fire up at all? Could you show us what SQL query does it generate?

Comment: Agreed with @KrzysiekDróżdż  This look it should work. "no luck so far" is not much of a bug report though. Please explain what is happening in more detail.

Comment: Hmm, so it's sorting correctly, but with wrong order? Are you sure that you have no typo in `$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );` in your code?